# Dot Product in vector analysis

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose I have a vector say v1=(1,2,3) and the dot product of another vector(v2) with v1 is zero. What other information do we need too find v2. I thought this seemed like a pretty trivial question however when I went to do it I had difficulty.

I know that a vector is a quantity with both magnitude and direction. So in other to get the vector v2 we would need its direction. due to the fact that you can have multiple different vectors prependicular. You would also need its magnitude. So is it the case that the dot product gives us almost no information in findng the vector v2,

Comment: Dot product equal to zero is orthogonality between $v_1,v_2$. Any $v_2\bot v_1$ would give $v_1\cdot v_2=0$.

Comment: All vectors lying in the plane perpendicular to $\vec{v}_1$ satisfy the condition. Thus, there are infinitely many such vectors. You need more information to determine $\vec{v}_2.$

Comment: the vector has three unknown components, so you need three linear equations to specify them. the scalar product gives you one of the three equations.

Comment: Yes I know that but I got an equation with 3 unknowns, I cant see how this would help me in determining the vector

Comment: @Harry: The point is that the vector $v_2$ is not uniquely determined by the condition $v_1\cdot v_2$. All that you know is that $v_2 = (-2s-3t, t, s)$ for some $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$. You need to specify two different pieces of information to determine what $s$ and $t$ are.

Answer (score 1):

In general the fact that $v_1\cdot v_2 = 0$ means that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal. In your case, you are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so that the set of vectors orthogonal to $v_1$ forms a plane (if you want to visualize this, think of $v_1$ as being the vector $\langle 1, 0, 0\rangle$ and think about the vectors perpendicular to this one). So you will need a lot more information than just length to figure out what $v_2$ is.

Even in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the set of vectors orthogonal to $v_1$ forms a line, so there are still an infinite number of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the definition of dot product...v2=(a,b,c) then v1.v2=a+2b+3c=0
Hint: Solve a+2b+3c=0 what do you get?

Comment: Yes I know that but there are infinetly many solutions.

Comment: Yes, think about a plane.

Comment: http://thejuniverse.org/PUBLIC/LinearAlgebra/LOLA/planes/normal.png

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I know hat 1,2,3 is normal to the plane, but I dont see how that helps.